# Can't uninstall Xoreax Incredibuild Visual Studio addin

Tags: visual-studio-2015, incredibuild

With some difficulty, I was able to uninstall Incredibuild (kept saying Visual Studio was open even when it wasn't), but it was unable to uninstall the Visual Studio addin (just said an error occurred when doing so in the log). The addin doesn't show up in Visual Studio's extensions dialog, and I don't know how else to uninstall it. I think it might be slowing VS down, and it never worked to begin with (kept asking for a license key and I was unable to find a key for the free edition I installed)...

Comment: My name is Yoni Davidson and I am from IncrediBuild support team.
The behavior you described is something we have not encountered before and it is possible that there a devenv.exe process running in the background that was preventing the uninstall process.
I am sorry that you had such experience with IncrediBuild. If you contact our support (support@incredibuild.com), I am sure that we will be able to walk you through so you will be able to enjoy IncrediBuild.

Comment: Any update, were you able to uninstall?

Comment: No, I still haven't been able to uninstall the addin. Haven't contacted the support person who commented here earlier because it honestly hasn't been *that* high a priority...

Comment: I had the incredibuild icon in my task bar for years showing an error that it wasn't registered.  I seemed like a neat idea, so I finally registered, learned about it and tried it.  It turns out it will not help with modestly sized C# projects.  I just uninstalled it for the third time.  All-in all, since it's applicability is limited, I think it would be better not to install it by default with Visual Studio.

Comment: try unchecking "Incredibuild" from visual studio installer.

Answer (score 6):

I had a similar issue (though I am in VS17 and not VS15).

1. (While in VS) Select **Tools** Menu
2. Select **Extensions and Updates...**
3. Find the Incredibuild add-in under "Installed" then click **Revert**
4. Close VS and wait for change to take affect then reopen VS
5. Find the Incredibuild add-in again just as before.
6. This time click **Uninstall** that is now visible
7. This should bring up the VS Installer where you need to close VS leaving VS Installer open
8. Click **Modify** in the bottom right for Incredibuild to finally be removed.

I honestly don't understand why it isn't removed when you uninstall Incredibuild because one of the processes listed while uninstalling is to remove the VS add-in or why the add-in doesn't initially have the option to uninstall but this is how I managed to finally remove it.

Hopefully this will help anyone.
Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

My name is Yoni and I work in IncrediBuild.

As Nathanael mentioned, this is indeed the way to remove IncrediBuild if it was installed from Visual Studio.
It can be also done from the "Manage Extension" menu in Visual Studio.
We are aware of the great confusion when it comes to removing IncrediBuild (after it was installed from Visual Studio) and this is something that we will try to solve or at least show a warning message that will alert from such scenarios.
Thank you all for the feedback - we are taking this very seriously and hopefully that in our future versions it will be solved.

Comment: the way he suggested is not valid for VS2019. when you select uninstall under installed extensions, VS installer is automatically starting and returns an error that Id not found. please describe it better how to fix it for VS2019.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue - I uninstalled Incredibuild successfully but the menu was available in VS2015 and VS2017 [the menu had disappeared other versions of Visual Studio].  Therefore in VS2015 I choose Customize from Add or Remove Buttons drop down.  In the popup I select Menu | Menu Bar.  Scroll down to Incredibuild.   Delete!  I repeat this for VS2015.  Done

Answer (score 0):

In Tools, select Customize. Go to Commands, select IncrediBuild in the list. Press on Delete.

In File, press Save All, so that you settings are remembered.

Answer (score -1):

1. Make sure Visual Studio is closed.
2. Right click on the Agent icon in the Windows System Tray, open the
   Agent Options, and disable the Agent service.
3. Make sure there are no errors or warnings in the fine print after
   the uninstall.

Your experience may vary because I obtained a license directly from their website, while there is probably another way to obtain it through Visual Studio.