# Can't remove IncrediBuild from VisualStudio 2019

Tags: visual-studio-2019, incredibuild

As mentioned in the title, I cannot seem to get rid of this app.

I have followed the directions posted [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39338469/cant-uninstall-xoreax-incredibuild-visual-studio-addin) and it still will not work.

EDIT: meaning, 1) I reverted the extension using the manager in VS2019 2) closed, reopened VS19 and then clicked uninstall 3) closed VS19 and clicked "Modify" in the VS Installer app, which removed ~250mbs of data.

The only functional change was removing IncrediBuild from VS19. Both services and the icon tray still load with windows. Using the IncrediBuild uninstall app just tells me to uninstall using VisualStudio. At this point, there's nothing left to do in VS19 and IncrediBuild is no where in sight.

There's another comment posted in that link from a user also stuck under VS19.

EDIT: meaning, I'm not the only one to try and follow the "given instructions on removing IncrediBuild", which apparently only works for VS15 and VS17.

Comment: Try unchecking "Incredibuild" from Visual studio installer.

Comment: I was wondering if this is still an issue. I work with IncrediBuild and although I have spotted this post a bit too late, I am interesting to understand how you have installed IncrediBuild in the first place. Also, what IncrediBuild version you have used. Most of our users are using VS2017 and VS2019 and usually such scenarios occurs when IncrediBuild is installed directly from VS installer and the removing process was done using the regular uninstaller and not from VS itself.
Anyway, please let me know.

Answer (score 2):

Ran into the same problem. Here's how I fixed it:

1. Remove IncrediBuild plugins from all versions of Visual Studio.
2. Use IncrediBuild Uninstaller to create a command line tool (IBSetupConsole.exe)
3. Run `IBSetupConsole.exe /uninstall`

Then it says, "Uninstall successfully completed".